# what is the name of the web color #ccc?

Tags: stylesheet

googled but no answer

Comment: Not all colors have web names. Do the math. can you name 16777216 colors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all colors have official names.

> W3C have listed only 17 valid color names:
>   aqua, black, blue, fuchsia, gray, grey, green, lime, maroon, navy, olive, purple, red, 
>   silver, teal, white, and yellow.

From [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_colornames.asp)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.perbang.dk says "Grey80", but that's probably inofficial.